# Stop images overriding table cell size

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have created an email flyer and it generate the products by pulling images from a server based on the pasrt code I input. The problem is that some images are bigger than others so I want to created table cells with a set height e.g. `100px` x `100px` but when the image is pulled into the cell, it over rides it and appears bigger than it should be.

I've tried setting either the height or the width so it doesn't get too big but some are wider than others so even though the height fits nice, the width then pushes the cell wider.

Is there no way to tell the image to fill as much of the cell as possible without expanding when it gets to the cells max size?

It's quite difficult to post the exact code I am using but if you just create a table with height="100" and insert an image larger than the cell it will ignore the cell height.

I can't set manual heights to images as I am using one table and it multiplies if I add more products.

**So basically want I want to do is set the table cell let's say to a height of `100px` and a width of `150px` and whatever the size the image "hits" first, it stops getting bigger**

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` on the cells in question doesn't do the trick?
You could also put the `img` tag into a div with width and height 100 and `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: @DanielKhan Hmm nope, nothing

Answer (score 1):

For your image add one class apply it like below. I hope you have assigned the width and height for your table cells.

```
.imgclass
{
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
}
```